# How do I Parse the response I get back from CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending some data to an external URL using Curl. The server sends me back a response in a string like this:

```
trnApproved=0&trnId=10000002&messageId=7&messageText=DECLINE
```

I can assign this string to a variable like this:

```
$txResult = curl_exec( $ch );
echo "Result:<BR>"; echo $txResult;
```

But how do I use the data that is sent back? I need a way to get the value of each variable sent back so that I can use it in my PHP script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($txResult, $txArr);
var_dump($txArr);
```

Answer (score 7):

The default behavior of Curl is to just dump the data you get back out to the browser. In order to instead capture it to a variable, you need:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$txResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

That default behavior has always annoyed me. Returning the data from the `curl_exec()` call  seems by far the more correct choice to me.