# PHP Parsing Freebase Query

Tags: php, echo, freebase

This will be the most basic question ever asked on this site! I am new to programming and very new to freebase - yet I couldn't find the answer I need anywhere, so here goes...

I am using the basic PHP query from [here](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) in my php file:

```
<?php
 // include('.freebase-api-key');
  $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
  $topic_id = '/en/bob_dylan';
  $params = array('key'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  $url = $service_url . $topic_id . '?' . http_build_query($params);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $topic = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $topic['property']['/type/object/name']['values'][0]['value'];
?>
```

And I have this working so that it displays a result (in this case just the name 'Bob Dylan') on my website.  My Question is, I need to pull down several pieces of info, like date of birth, nationality, death,etc... But I just cannot figure out how to access, parse and display it via echo $topic[?????????];.

How does one figure out what to put here:  echo $topic['????'];

I would like to have a result on my website something like this:

```
Name: Bob Dylan
Born: May 24, 1941
Died: -
Nationality: American
Parents: ???, ???
Children:  ???, ???
```

Apologies for the extremely newb question just not sure where else to turn.

Thank You!!

.
.
.
.
.
Thanks nicolas for responding. I followed that website you posted and tried this instead:

```
$service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
  $topic_id = '/en/bob_dylan';
  $params = array('key'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  $url = $service_url . $topic_id . '?' . http_build_query($params);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $topic = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  curl_close($ch);
  parse_str($topic, $txArr);
  var_dump($txArr);
```

But that gives me the following results on my site: **array(1) { ["Array"]=> string(0) "" }**

I hear the sound of many palms hitting foreheads out there as they read this...like I said I am a greenhorn and appreciate some help, so thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459865/how-do-i-parse-the-response-i-get-back-from-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the 2nd part of your question you really need to understand how JSON data works and how your code above is parsing it.

If you add /people/person/ethnicity to your query it would look like this in PHP:

```
$query = array(array(
  'id' => '/m/02mjmr', 
  '/people/person/gender' => NULL, 
  '/people/person/date_of_birth' => NULL, 
  '/people/person/height_meters' => NULL,
  '/people/person/ethnicity' => array()
));
```

This query gets translated into the following JSON object:

```
[{
  "id": "/m/02mjmr",
  "/people/person/gender": null,
  "/people/person/date_of_birth": null,
  "/people/person/height_meters": null,
  "/people/person/ethnicity": []
}]
```

That JSON object is then URL encoded and added to the API request URL like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{%22id%22:%22/m/02mjmr%22,%22/people/person/gender%22:null,%22/people/person/date_of_birth%22:null,%22/people/person/height_meters%22:null,%22/people/person/ethnicity%22:[]}]
```

If you open that URL in your web browser, you'll see the JSON object that gets returned by the Freebase API:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "/people/person/gender": "Male", 
      "/people/person/ethnicity": [
        "English American", 
        "Kenyan American", 
        "Irish American", 
        "Multiracial American"
      ], 
      "id": "/m/02mjmr", 
      "/people/person/date_of_birth": "1961-08-04", 
      "/people/person/height_meters": 1.85
    }
  ]
}
```

In your code, this data is parsed back into PHP array objects and stored in the $response variable like this:

```
array(
  'result' => array(array(
    '/people/person/ethnicity' => array(
      'English American', 
      'Kenyan American', 
      'Irish American', 
      'Multiracial American'
    ),
    'id' => '/m/02mjmr', 
    '/people/person/date_of_birth' => '1961-08-04', 
    '/people/person/height_meters' => 1.85
  ))
)
```

Now if you want to loop over every topic that was returned from the Freebase API, you can do that in PHP like this:

```
foreach ($response['result'] as $topic) { ... }
```

Notice how we use square braces to tell it to iterate though each of the objects contained within the `'result'` array entry in $response. For the query you gave, there's only one topic returned so the first and only time through the loop the value of $topic is:

```
array(
  '/people/person/ethnicity' => array(
    'English American', 
    'Kenyan American', 
    'Irish American', 
    'Multiracial American'
  ),
  'id' => '/m/02mjmr', 
  '/people/person/date_of_birth' => '1961-08-04', 
  '/people/person/height_meters' => 1.85
)
```

Now, you're able to access the data within $topic by using those same square braces to drill down one more level like this:

```
echo $topic['/people/person/gender'];
```

By combining this with the foreach loop that we used above we can iterate over all of the ethnicity values like this:

```
foreach ($topic['/people/person/ethnicity'] as $ethnicity) {
  echo $ethnicity;
}
```

I hope that this gives you a better understanding of how to navigate your way through JSON data. By understanding the techniques I've described above, you should be able to parse any value out of any Freebase query.

If at any point you need to debug the value of a variable that contains some JSON data you can print it to the screen like this:

```
echo json_encode($topic['/people/person/ethnicity'])
```

Comment: Wow, Shawn, Thank You! You just helped me out so much, I truly appreciate the time you spent writing and explaining that to me. You are very kind. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found a new example here: https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview and I have that working as follows:

```
$query = array(array('id' => '/m/02mjmr', '/people/person/gender' => NULL, '/people/person/date_of_birth' => NULL, '/people/person/height_meters' => NULL));
        $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread';
        $params = array(
                'query' => json_encode($query),
                'key' => 'AIzaSyAPLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8INnsk7b2oxgc'
        );
        $url = $service_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        curl_close($ch);
        foreach ($response['result'] as $topic) {
                echo "Gender:  "; echo $topic['/people/person/gender'] . '<br/>';
                echo "Born:  "; echo $topic['/people/person/date_of_birth'] . '<br/>';
                echo "Height (meters):  "; echo $topic['/people/person/height_meters'] . '<br/>';
```

And this is what the return looks like:

```
Gender: Male
Born: 1961-08-04
Height (meters): 1.85
```

This is exactly what I am looking for BUT one last thing to figure out is how to query for and display multiple properties. I can't include "/people/person/ethnicity" in my query because it returns multiple responses and breaks my code.

So, if someone could chime in on how to make the multi-response query and display possible that would be swell.

Thanks for the help!